# How to copy a WP website to new domain name?

Tags: backup

I have my https://example.com on my server1.
I need to migrate it to https://new.example.com on my server2

This task can be long: dump database, copy all files, find and change all recurrences in DB, config files from "example.com" to "new.example.com"

I guess there are many plugins to backup a website or to migrate using the same domain name.

But not sure they can also change the domain name.

Answer (score 0):

use the plugin "wp all in one", this will migrate your website, other way is to do it manually, copy all files, make a copy or your database and do the inverse on the new server.

wp all in one  make everything for you, even changing on the database the urls, manually you need to go to the database and change it manually.